# Writing string to TMemoryStream - Pointer to string

Tags: delphi

What is the difference between

this:

```
SourceString := 'I am doing just fine!';     
MemoryStream.ReadBuffer(Pointer(SourceString)^, xxx);
```

(full source code available here: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/26416)

and this code (mine):

```
SetLength(SourceString, xxx);
MemoryStream.ReadBuffer(SourceString[1], xxx);
```

1. Do I really have to use Pointer(SourceString)^ or SourceString[1] is ok also?
2. The code (both of them) will work with Delphi 2010 (unicode)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: The `SourceString[1]` version is more readable. I prefer not to work with pointers when they aren't completely necessary.

2: This code will *not* work with Unicode.  You'll have to multiply it: `xxx * sizeof(Char)`.  (This will work with both pre- and post-Unicode versions of Delphi.)  But unless you're making heavy use of non-Ansi chars, this will be a big waste of space.  What I prefer to do is:

```
procedure TStreamEx.WriteString(const data: string);
var
  len: cardinal;
  oString: UTF8String;
begin
  oString := UTF8String(data);
  len := length(oString);
  self.WriteBuffer(len, 4);
  if len > 0 then
    self.WriteBuffer(oString[1], len);
end;

procedure TStreamEx.ReadString(const data: string);
var
  len: cardinal;
  iString: UTF8String;
begin
  self.ReadBuffer(len, 4);
  if len > 0 then
  begin
    SetLength(iString, len);
    self.ReadBuffer(iString[1], len);
    result := string(iString);
  end
  else result := '';
end;
```

(This is part of a `class helper for TStream` I wrote that makes it a lot easier to read and write various things to and from streams.  But if you don't like class helpers, it shouldn't be too hard to adapt the basic idea to a different format.)

Comment: "This is part of a class helper for TStream" - My code is also from a class helper of my own :) Though I was pretty sure it will not work with Delphi 2010 unless I change the string to AnsiString (which I just did recently). Though, I am not really interested in saving UNICOE, I admit, I will update my code (using yours) to support UNICODE. Thanks.

Comment: SourceString[1] version is more readable - Thanks for confirmation Mason. I have found the code on Borland's web site and I thought "it must be something with it, if they are giving it as example". What's the point of doing it more complicated that it should?

Comment: When you have range checking enabled (and you should always have range checking enabled), then `SourceString[1]` will raise an exception when the length is zero, whereas `Pointer(SourceString)` will be a null pointer, and that won't get dereferenced since the byte count you pass in is also zero. See *Listing 4* at [my Web site](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/string-stream).

Comment: Mason, class helpers can be very good, but beware if you are using them, because if you will use a third party library for instance that also uses a helper for TStream one will not work. As you probably know only one class helper can be used for one class. I would advise against them for this alone. They are great if you use them on you own internal classes, but not for TStream which is a part of Delphi itself.

Answer (score 2):

In the generated asm code:

- **pointer(aString)^** will pass the string address directly to the procedure/function/method;
- **aString[1]** will call **UniqueString** then pass the string address to the procedure/function/method.

So **pointer(aString)^** is to be used if you're about to read the data, not modify it.

And **aString[1]** is to be used if you're about to modify aString in the called function.

In practice, I use **pointer(aString)^** which produces more efficient code.

Note that this implicit **UniqueString** is not so slow: if the current reference count of the string is 1 (which means that there is only one part of your code using the string, which is very likely), it returns immediately. But there is a LOCK asm prefix in the **UniqueString** used to check the reference count value, and use of this LOCK asm is not multi-thread friendly. That's why I try to avoid using **aString[1]** when I'm coding.

Additional note: if **aString** is '', **pointer(aString)** will return **nil**.

Comment: In other words, pointer(aString)^ is faster while aString[1] is safer?

Comment: you can say that :) but in some cases, the implicit call to UniqueString is mandatory to avoid memory corruption: you can use an explicit UniqueString call before using pointer(aString)^ if you want your code to be both safe and fast